# 403 error when accessing blob storage from Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

Either I'm doing something silly or there's a bug. I have a blob storage account configured to allow public access from a limited IP address set. All my resources are in East US region. I've got the latest IP addresses for Azure Data Factory for EastUS region and have added them to the whitelist for blob storage:

```
          "20.42.2.0/23",
          "20.42.4.0/26",
          "20.42.64.0/28",
          "20.49.111.0/29",
          "20.119.28.57/32",
          "20.232.89.104/29",
          "40.71.14.32/28",
          "40.78.229.96/28"
```

I am using key based access (connection string) and can access blob storage from my Azure Data Factory linked service when I enable public access from all networks. The minute I restrict access to specific IPs only, it throws a 403 when testing the linked service connection, despite having the addresses above in the whitelist.

Is there a way to see which IP is attempting to access blob storage to confirm that it's one of those in the list provided by Microsoft for Azure Data Factory East US?

Comment: I think I've found the issue:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/azure-integration-runtime-ip-addresses
Known issue with Azure Storage
When connecting to Azure Storage account, IP network rules have no effect on requests originating from the Azure integration runtime in the same region as the storage account. For more details, please refer this article.

Instead, we suggest using trusted services while connecting to Azure Storage.

Answer (score 0):

> 403 error when accessing blob storage from Azure Data Factory

When you want to connect firewalled enabled Storage account to Azure data factory you need to create **Managed private endpoints** from ADF and the approve it from you storage account.

To create managed private endpoints:

- First create new integration runtime with **Virtual network configuration** is `Enable`.
  [image]
- Then create a **Managed private endpoint** for storage account.
  [image]
- Select your subscription and storage account and click on create.
  [image]
- After this go to your storage account >> Networking >>Private endpoint connection >> and **Approve** private endpoint
  [image]
- Then create a linked service with Integration runtime we created and select Subscription and Storage account it will automatically detect managed private endpoint. and connected successfully.
  [image]